# MySQL Query, trying to gather count

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to write a query that gets the amount of artists and bands for each recordlabel in my database. For some reason, when I run the below query, it is not listing every recordlabel assigned to a band or artist in my database.

```
 SELECT  r.labelName, 
        COUNT(a.recordLabelID) +COUNT(b.recordLabelID) AS count 
        FROM recordLabel r JOIN artist a ON r.recordLabelID = a.recordLabelID
        JOIN band b ON r.recordLabelID = b.recordLabelID
        GROUP BY r.recordlabelID ORDER BY count DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `left join`:

```
SELECT r.labelName, COUNT(a.recordLabelID) + COUNT(b.recordLabelID) AS count
FROM recordLabel r JOIN
     artist a
     ON r.recordLabelID = a.recordLabelID JOIN
     band b
     ON r.recordLabelID = b.recordLabelID
GROUP BY r.recordlabelID
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

However, that will not work, because the counts will return the same value.  An easy fix is to use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT r.labelName,
       COUNT(DISTINCT a.recordLabelID) + COUNT(DISTINCT b.recordLabelID) AS count
FROM recordLabel r LEFT JOIN
     artist a
     ON r.recordLabelID = a.recordLabelID LEFT JOIN
     band b
     ON r.recordLabelID = b.recordLabelID
GROUP BY r.recordlabelID
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

You need to use `LEFT JOIN`, in case some labels have artists but not bands, or vice versa.

A more scalable solution is to aggregate *before* doing the joins.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
FROM recordLabel r 
LEFT JOIN artist a ON r.recordLabelID = a.recordLabelID
LEFT JOIN band b ON r.recordLabelID = b.recordLabelID
```